# Pass arguments to python functions using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

If I have a function in a file like this:

```
def foo():
    print 'foo'

foo()
```

I can call this file from another one:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python', 'function.py'])
```

But can if the function needs arguments:

```
def foo(foo_var):
    print foo_var
```

Can I still call the function using subprocess?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to call a Python function using `subprocess` instead of importing it???

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm just learning to use subprocess, I now it's better to import the function, I was just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I still call the function using subprocess?

Yeah.

First you will need to pass the arguments to the function:

```
from sys import argv

def foo(args):
    print args
    >> ['arg1', 'arg2']  # (based on the example below)

foo(argv[1:])
```

Then in your calling code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python', 'function.py', 'arg1', 'arg2'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `subprocess`, just modify `function.py` to have it work nicely with imports:

```
def foo():
    print 'foo'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

Then you can just import `foo` from the `function` module:

```
from function import foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo(1)
```