# Add function argument to subprocess popen

Tags: python, subprocess

Can you add an argument to your python function from inside a `subprocess.popen` call?
I know you can pass arguments to `subprocess.popen` by using the argv module in the python file that you are trying to use. Reference(https://stackoverflow.com/a/36984601/18023285)

However, I don't want to do that unless there is no other choice. I have thousands of functions that I would need to this to do and I don't want to have to rewrite all my functions to use argv instead of the variables they already have.

Here is my code:

```
testdata = "words"
subprocess.Popen(['python', '-u','-c', f"""from test import counttest; counttest({testdata})"""]
```

If I run that I get:

```
NameError: name 'words' is not defined
```

Is there anyway to add an argument to a function in subprocess.popen? If there is no other choice I will have to bite the bullet and rewrite thousands of functions.

Comment: This is just inserting "words" into a format string before creating a process. Output what it resolves to and the error should become obvious. I'm not sure, but I believe you should rather look into multiprocessing and the according Python modules.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Can you add an argument to a function in subprocess without using the argv module as mentioned here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36984601/18023285 I am just looking for subprocess NOT multiprocessing please. Again if the answer is that what I am looking is not possible, then I will accept that.

Comment: What I mean with what?

Comment: Nevermind - I will just remove the google account, create a new account with a vpn and ask the question in a different way. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe you should start with the [tour] and read [ask] for a start as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments are substituted before calling subprocess.Popen, therefore you spawn process with arguments:

`'-u','-c', 'from test import counttest; counttest(words)'`

If you want `words` to be used as a string, put in in quotes in your code:

```
testdata = "words"
subprocess.Popen(['python', '-u','-c', f"""from test import counttest; counttest("{testdata}")"""]
```